# Colors (h,s,b) from 360 to 0 and from 0 to (-360) and from (-360) to (-720) and so on

Tags: javascript, colors, hsb

I've got a HSB color problem and don't know how to calculate it in the right way.

I've got Hue of a color between `360` and `0` and if i substrate `-1` from `0` i get the value `-1` and not `360`. I'think i've to do something with modulo to get the right values ?! so my problem is to convert a multiple of a unit to a number between 0 and 360. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A negative hue value is equivalent to `360 + value`, that means -10 is equivalent to 350. To achieve that behavior do:

```
var val = -10; // or whatever your value is
var hue = (val + 360) % 360 // --> 350
```

That works also correctly with positive values, val = 380 --> hue = 20. If you are dealing with values greater than +/- 360 simply add `720` (or 1080, 1440, ...) instead of `360` before doing % 360.

We can wrap it in a handy function that whatever you input always returns a value between 0 and 360:

```
function adjustHue(val) {
    if (val < 0) val += Math.ceil(-val / 360) * 360;
    return val % 360;
}
```